# How to make Flutter Liquide wave animation

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-design

How can I make liquids wave animation which is always flowing .
can any one Help me.

Comment: Do you have a video or gif demo of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Something like [this](https://pub.dev/packages/liquid_progress_indicator_ns) ?

Comment: @Ajil O. This same I need . Thank you soo much bro